# Wolfram Mathematica Return[] strange result?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm a bit confused about, how does Return[], returns result from function. For example, take those two functions:

```js
CalcLossTotal = Function[
   {data, units},

   Clear[i];
   Return[Table[
     data[[i, 1]]*units,
     {i, 1, Length[data]}]
    ];
   ];
```

and

```js
CalcPremiums = Function[
   {data, lossTotal},

   Clear[i];
   Return[Table[
     data[[i, 2]]*lossTotal[[i]],
     {i, 1, Length[data]}]
    ];
   ];
```

wheres CalcPremiums[] depends upon CalcLossTotal[] and data which is same for both of them. Upon calculating LossTotal (e.g. result from CalcLossTotal[]), result returned from it isn't array of data, but

```
Return[{0,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000,8000,9000,10000}]
```

Is this the way Mathematica works, or there is something that i miss when defining/returning from functions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534324/how-does-return-work/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construct you want is this:

```
CalcPremiums[data_, lossTotal_] := (
  Return[Table[data[[i, 2]]*lossTotal[[i]], {i, 1, Length[data]}]];)
```

note that return is superflous if you are returning the final result so,

```
CalcPremiums[data_, lossTotal_] := (
  Table[data[[i, 2]]*lossTotal[[i]], {i, 1, Length[data]}]);
```

(note no semicolon after  Table[] inside the parenthesis) The parenthesis are not needed here either but I left them in assuming you really have a multi line function.

I must say I'm a bit puzzled why your construt returns "return[]". Consider this:

```
g = Function[u, If[u < 0, Return[u], 0]];
f[x_] := (
    y = g[x] ;
    {x, y})
```

for x<0 the effect of the pure Function (g) is to Return x from the calling function (f), not to set y=x.

```
 f[-1]-> -1   , f[1] -> {1,0}
```

I see the logic but it's not obvious to me.

Comment: Thanks a lot, saved me a lot of time. :)

Comment: @george - That's interesting. The following definition of `g` does what you intended though: `g = Function[u, Catch[If[u < 0, Throw[u], 0]]]`

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess the problem is an effect of [Function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) having the attribute `HoldAll`.

Your functions will work if rewritten like so:-

```
CalcLossTotal = Function[
   {data, units},

   Catch[
    Clear[i];
    Throw[Table[
      data[[i, 1]]*units,
      {i, 1, Length[data]}]
     ];
    ]];


CalcPremiums = Function[
   {data, lossTotal},

   Catch[
    Clear[i];
    Throw[Table[
      data[[i, 2]]*lossTotal[[i]],
      {i, 1, Length[data]}]
     ];
    ]];
```